# Rails rspec filtering test failed with 0 result and undefined method '[]'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to check if the filtering method for closed `bank_offers` is working properly. If I change status in one of the earlier defined `bank_offer` to `:expired` specs works well but I have to nest new `bank_offer` in to this `context 'filtering'`

**not_working_specs**

```
describe 'filtering' do
  subject(:call) do
    get endpoint, headers: authorized_headers(token: token), params: params
  end

  context "when status 'closed' passed " do
    let(:credit_5) { create :credit, company: company, details: details }
    let(:credit_process_5) { create :credit_process, credit: credit_5 }
    let(:suggestion_5) { create :bank_suggestion, bank: user.bank }
    let(:some_user) { create :bank_advisor, bank: user.bank }

    before do
      create :bank_offer,
             credit_process: credit_process_5,
             bank_suggestion: suggestion_5,
             bank_advisor: some_user,
             status: :expired,
             created_at: 5.days.ago,
             closed_at: 2.days.ago

      params[:filters][:general_status] = 'closed'
    end

    it 'returns only closed bank offers', :aggregate_failures do
      call
      data = json_response_body['data']
      expect(data.count).to eq(1)
      expect(data.first['id']).to eq(second.id.to_s)
    end
  end
end
```

At the end I've got 2 errors:

> 1.1) Failure/Error: expect(data.count).to eq(1)
>
> ```
>         expected: 1
>              got: 0
> ```
>
> and the second which is result from the first error:
>
> ```
>  1.2) Failure/Error: expect(data.first['id']).to eq(second.id.to_s)
>
>       NoMethodError:
>         undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
> ```

As I said before, the method works correctly because if I change the status of the previously defined `bank_offer` to `closed`, I will not have an error. Unfortunately, I need it in 20 other `IT` tests so I want to nest only one closed case.

Here are working specs, without nested bank attributes:

```
describe 'filtering' do
  subject(:call) do
    get endpoint, headers: authorized_headers(token: token), params: params
  end

  context "when status 'closed' passed " do

    before do
      params[:filters][:general_status] = 'closed'
    end

    it 'returns only closed bank offers', :aggregate_failures do
      call
      data = json_response_body['data']
      expect(data.count).to eq(1)
      expect(data.first['id']).to eq(second.id.to_s)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't know your controller's code, but this looks more like a model spec than a controller spec. You could call a method on the model to filter the data, the model spec will check it returns the expected recordes. The controller spec should only check if the model receives the expected method call. It will be faster te execute and easier to test in a model spec.

Comment: It's in `app/api/v1/...` folder so it looks like it's a Grape or something